# Larger Than N (revisited)

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am currently working through textbook problems preparing for a final exam and am stuck on methods and arrays. I see someone else posted about this question before, but i think they were seeking homework help and reading that post did not assist me.  The prompt:

*In a program, write a method that accepts two arguments: an array and a number n. Assume the array contains integers. The method should display all of the numbers in the array that are greater than the number n.*

I think I have set up an array and print all of the numbers larger than my "n" variable, but I'm not sure if I am answering the question.  I feel as though I have not done this in a method.  I may be slightly confused on what a method is to be honest.  Here is my current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //initialize n
    int n = 3;

    //setup the array
    int [] integerArray = new int [] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};


    for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
        if (i>n) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }

    }


}
```

I'm not getting errors when I run it, but, like I said, I feel as though it was too easy and I must be missing something.  I really appreciate the assistance for a beginner like myself.  My goal is to then take this and ask the user for their numbers to fill the array and also their "n" to make it more practical and give myself more practice using JOptionPane, but first things first.

Comment: ... *write a method that takes*

Comment: `if (i>n) { ` is this what you should be comparing?

Comment: I'm should be printing the values in the array that are larger than the value of "n"

Comment: Two things... First, you should create a new method "that accepts two arguments" as the prompt says instead of having the logic in main. Second, you need to compare the array's *value* at index i to n, not the index itself.

Comment: @spencer.sm Ok.  So I haven't actually written a method then?  I would need something like public static int (int integerArray[], int n); ?

Comment: @ZacharyMull No, you've just put your code *inside* the main method. You'll need to create a new method that "accepts two arguments: an array and a number n". Then you can call that new method from inside the main method.

Comment: @ZacharyMull I have updated my answer. You can also extract he method for comparison logic if needed. Otherwise it'll also run fine.

Comment: @Shubham Thank you.  I'll take a look at it.  I feel like Spencer is onto something.  I shouldn't have this in the main.

Comment: @spencer.sm so I would need to make a new method, something like: public static void (int [] integerArray() , int n) ?

Comment: Its upto you. Ideally you should extract the comparison logic into a method public static void methodName(int[] arr, int num) and call it from main. In this method you can write the logic

Comment: Ok.  I think I understand.  Thank you @Shubham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the main point is that you gave the logic but there is no method written that has as parameters an int array and an int and return nothing as result (apart printing) therefore it is missing the method as requested; a solution is like that:

```
private static void printGreaterThanN(int[] intArray, int valN) {
    IntStream intStream1 = Arrays.stream(intArray);
    intStream1.forEach(x -> { if (x > valN) System.out.println(x); });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what is missing.  I really appreciate your help!  I hope this becomes more intuitive as I move forward.  Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome Zachary, it's another way to avoid to use indexes, yes it's just to keep practicing and doing examples ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the value not the index. It should be

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter number of elements");
    int num=s.nextInt();
    int integerArray[]=new int[num];

    System.out.println("enter elements");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){//for reading array
        integerArray[i]=s.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter number to be compared");
    int n = s.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
    if (integerArray[i]>n) { //not the index i
        System.out.println(integerArray[i]);

    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: OK so when you put integerArray[i] that gives me the values and I am currently just comparing their index locations?

Comment: Yes,currently in your program you're comparing the index with n.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the help.  So other than that, I have written a method that accepts the arguments:  an array and a number n?

Comment: I think it does.  Just to confirm, with your correction for the index vs the actual values, I have written a method that accepts the arguments: an array and a number n?

Comment: @ZacharyMull You have taken hardcoded array and a number. And on that you are printing the array elements which are greater than the number (if you compare the array value and not the index). So if you modify the method as suggested in answer then yes you'll have a method which will take user input and will print values on that.